# Integral with floor function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find the integral
$$\int_1^{1000}\frac{dx}{x+⌊\log_{10}(x)⌋}$$ The logarithm is creating some problems along with floor function.

Comment: I would rather say that **without the floor function** the logarithm would create problems. The floor function is locally constant, so can you see how to best split this into subintervals, where that applies?

Comment: Is that $\log(x)$ to base $10$, $e$, or another base? The easiest answer would come with base $10$.

Comment: Yep, its base 10.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have that $\lfloor \log_{10}(x)\rfloor $ equals $0$ for $x\in(0,10)$, $1$ for $x\in[10,100)$ and $2$ for $x\in[100,1000)$, hence the value of the integral is just:
$$ \int_{1}^{10}\frac{dx}{x}+\int_{10}^{100}\frac{dx}{x+1}+\int_{100}^{1000}\frac{dx}{x+2}=\log(10)+\log\frac{101}{11}+\log\frac{1002}{102}$$
or:
$$ \color{red}{\log\frac{168670}{187}}.$$

Comment: @TheGreatDuck What indefinite integral? The question is about a definite integral. This answer is correct.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Not the only way. By far. Never heard about the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), for instance? Often it's impossible to compute explicitly the antiderivative. Even if it's possible, it's often tricky and very convoluted. Here is another example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942983/find-int-02-pi-frac15-4-cos-x-dx

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I disagree. And compared to the crystal clear solution in Jack d'Aurizio's answer, *yours* is a mess. The question is easy, your are making it overly complicated.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Without sounding rude or anything, you should check your facts before arguing.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$n\le\log_{10}(10x)<n+1\iff10^n\le(10x)<10^{n+1}$$

For example, $n=1,10\le(10x)<100\iff1\le x<10$

Comment: Please see the edit, and please elaborate and edit.

Comment: @Garvil, Have you understood the method?Edit is not required

Comment: No, that is why I asked you to **elaborate**

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Why?? This hint is to split the definite integral into suitable intervals, which is adequate in this case.