# Evaluating $\int\sqrt{1+\sin x}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral is:$$\int\sqrt{1+\sin x} dx$$

My first attempt was to multiply by: 
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}$$

giving:
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}dx$$
which is:
$$\int\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}dx$$
then make the substitution:
$$u=1-\sin x$$
which gives
$$\int\frac{-1}{\sqrt{u}}du$$
which gives:
$$-2\sqrt{u}+c$$
so:
$$I=-2\sqrt{1-\sin x}+c$$
but I am not sure if this is correct.

Also sorry if the formatting is a bit rubbish

Comment: Differentiate and check...

Comment: what is the derivative of $1-\sin{x}$?

Comment: yep just spotted i missed out a few minus signs, have added them

Comment: Don't forget the $+c$.

Comment: added it to the final line now

Comment: looks [correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+-2sqrt(1-sin(x))) to me.

Comment: It should be noted that, while correct in some sense, your method is going to yield an antiderivative that is periodic and not everywhere differentiable, to a function that is continuous and positive on $\Bbb R$ (hence should have a monotonically increasing antiderivative on $\Bbb R$, of course everywhere differentiable). See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942983/find-int-02-pi-frac15-4-cos-x-dx/1943009#1943009) for an explanation on a similar problem. Also, you failed to notice that $\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}=|\cos x|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I = \int \sqrt{1+\sin x}dx$$
Apply substitution $ u=\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ 
([Tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution))
$$\int \frac{2\sqrt{\left(u+1\right)^2}}{\left(1+u^2\right)\sqrt{u^2+1}}du$$
$$2\int \frac{u+1}{\left(1+u^2\right)\sqrt{u^2+1}}du$$
$$2\left(\underbrace{\int \frac{u}{\left(1+u^2\right)\sqrt{u^2+1}}du}_{I_1}+\underbrace{\int \frac{1}{\left(1+u^2\right)\sqrt{u^2+1}}du}_{I_2}\right)$$

Set $v=1+u^2$
$$I_1 = \int \frac{1}{2v\sqrt{v}}dv = \frac{1}{2}\int v^{-\frac{3}{2}}dv =\frac{1}{2}\frac{v^{\left(-\frac{3}{2}+1\right)}}{\left(-\frac{3}{2}+1\right)} =-\frac{1}{\sqrt{v}}=  -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}$$

By [Trigonometric substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) $u=\tan \left(v\right)$
$$I_2 = \int \frac{1}{\left(u^2+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}du= \int \frac{\sec ^2\left(v\right)}{\left(\tan ^2\left(v\right)+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dv = \int \frac{\sec ^2\left(v\right)}{\sec ^3\left(v\right)}dv =\int \frac{1}{\sec \left(v\right)}dv =\int \cos \left(v\right)dv =\sin \left(v\right) +C$$
$$I_2 = \sin \left(v\right) = \sin \left(\arctan \left(u\right)\right) = \frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}$$
So
$$ I = 2\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}+\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\right) +C$$

> $$I = 2\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}+\frac{\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{1+\tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}\right) +C$$

Comment: how do you see to make this substitution?

Comment: @HenryLee It's pretty standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution The only exception is that, if the $\cos$ or $\sin$ in your integrand is always raised to an even power, use $u=\tan x$ instead. (See if you can understand why, in terms of periods.)

Comment: Same comment as above: not valid on the largest interval possible (which would be $\Bbb R$). But +1 anyway as it's the standard wrong way to do it.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks for your comment and(+1). why "standard wrong way"? How would you solve it?

Comment: Well, notwithstanding the fact that your derivation is not entirely satisfying ($\sqrt{(1+u)^2}=|1+u|$), the discontinuous solution that you will obtain can be adjusted by a constant on intervals where it's continuous, so as to have only removable singularities, and then you get a continuous antiderivative. Of course that may be considered overly complicated (a teacher may be asking just the Weierstrass transformation), but your result is a periodic function, while the integrand is continuous and nonnegative (thus has an antiderivative everywhere, monotonically increasing).

Comment: And I write it's the *"standard wrong way"* beause, to be honest, I have very rarely seen this addressed correctly, and almost nobody seems to care, teachers included, computer algebra systems included. However, the link I give above shows that it can hurt badly those who don't understand the limitations of this method of integration (you can't compute a definite integral without taking care of intervals).