# How can I make a piecewise function?

Tags: functions

How can I make a function that returns $g(x)$ if $x$ belongs to $(0,10)$ and returns $h(x)$ if not? Like this
:$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
    \ g(x) &   0<x<10,\\
    h(x) & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
I think it's like an if-else block in a programming language

Comment: What do you mean by "make"? It's more or less what you have written (except it's $0<x<10$). You don't need anything else to define such a piecewise function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise#Notation_and_interpretation

Comment: For example i have this: $\begin{align}
f(x)&=
\begin{cases}
g(x)\phantom{x}\forall\phantom{x} x\text{ even}\\
h(x)\phantom{x}\forall\phantom{x} x\text{ odd}
\end{cases}\\
\\
f(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+(-1)^{x}\right)\cdot g(x)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-(-1)^{x}\right)\cdot h(x)
\end{align}$

Comment: that's what I mean by "make"

Comment: Not a very good idea. To begin with, how do you define $(-1)^x$ when $x$ is not an integer? Often, it's absolutely not practical to resort to such tricks to write a piecewise function as a single expression, as you are only left with something more complicated. Sometimes there is a clever way (see for instance [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1943009/43608) and the comments). Or you may use [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), which are just a notation trick to replace the usual piecewise definition.